# Single query gives more result than same query UNION another?

Tags: sql, union, universe

I'm not sure if I misunterstood a basic thing or if I have a problem with how my database interprets the query... Running universe

When I run

```
SELECT POIDSBRUT, PRIXBRUTU, FAMILLENU, TPSMOU, TPSMOUPLANIF, QTE1PLANIFMOU, OF5
FROM GPSOF
WHERE DFINPLANIFMOU >= '%1' AND DFINPLANIFMOU <= '%2' AND EQPLANIFMOU <> 'A placer' AND EQPLANIFMOU LIKE 'A%'
```

It gives me 5 results (everything is normal here).

But when I run

```
SELECT POIDSBRUT, PRIXBRUTU, FAMILLENU, TPSMOU, TPSMOUPLANIF, QTE1PLANIFMOU, OF5
FROM GPSOF
WHERE DFINPLANIFMOU >= '%1' AND DFINPLANIFMOU <= '%2' AND EQPLANIFMOU <> 'A placer' AND EQPLANIFMOU LIKE 'A%'
UNION 
SELECT POIDSBRUT, PRIXBRUTU, FAMILLENU, TPSMOU, TPSMOU2PLANIF, QTE2PLANIFMOU, OF5
FROM GPSOF
WHERE DFIN2PLANIFMOU >= '%1' AND DFIN2PLANIFMOU <= '%2' AND EQ2PLANIFMOU <> 'A placer' AND EQ2PLANIFMOU LIKE 'A%'
UNION 
SELECT POIDSBRUT, PRIXBRUTU, FAMILLENU, TPSMOU, TPSMOU3PLANIF, QTE3PLANIFMOU, OF5
FROM GPSOF 
WHERE DFIN3PLANIFMOU >= '%1' AND DFIN3PLANIFMOU <= '%2' AND EQ3PLANIFMOU <> 'A placer' AND EQ3PLANIFMOU LIKE 'A%'
```

I get only 2 results. Either I didn't understand how UNION is suposed to work or I have another problem with my database...
Thanks

Comment: i think the first query gives you duplicates while the second doesn't. also, the second query has 2 more select s where you select other columns.

Comment: Exactly, `union` removes duplicates....I think that you need to use `union all` in order to replicate the same behaviour.

Comment: Does it remove duplicate based on primary key ?

Comment: Removes duplicate rows! (Based on the selected columns.)

Comment: Indeed it works with union all, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A UNION statement effectively does a SELECT DISTINCT on the results set. If you know that all the records returned are unique from your union, use UNION ALL instead, it gives faster results.

[Source (nice blog post on UNION performance)](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/)

Answer (score 1):

UNION removes duplicates- I'm guessing 4 of the records in your first result set are identical?

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using `union` for this query?  Why not just select the rows that you want?

```
SELECT POIDSBRUT, PRIXBRUTU, FAMILLENU, TPSMOU, TPSMOUPLANIF, 
       (CASE WHEN EQPLANIFMOU LIKE 'A%' THEN QTE1PLANIFMOU
             WHEN EQPLAN2IFMOU LIKE 'A%' THEN QTE2PLANIFMOU
             WHEN EQPLAN3IFMOU LIKE 'A%' THEN QTE3PLANIFMOU
        END) as QTE1PLANIFMOU,
       OF5
FROM GPSOF
WHERE DFINPLANIFMOU >= '%1' AND DFINPLANIFMOU <= '%2' AND EQPLANIFMOU <> 'A placer' AND
      (EQPLANIFMOU LIKE 'A%' OR
       EQPLAN2IFMOU LIKE 'A%' OR
       EQPLAN3IFMOU LIKE 'A%' 
      )
```

Comment: That's because each queries have conditions on different cols (DFIN/DFIN2/DFIN3)

Comment: @neyte . . . That is easily handled the same way it is handled for the last set of conditions.